# Error packaging SharePoint App with gulp, 'package-solution' sub task

Tags: gulp, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am having an issue packaging a SharePoint App.  Based on the documentation, we need to run:

```
npm install
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

On the last statement: `gulp package-solution --ship` I get the following error:

> Error - 'package-solution' sub task errored after 42 ms
> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> 'package-solution' errored after 50 ms

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a missing section in the file `package-solution.json`.

There need to be a `developer` section, see below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
    "solution": {
        "name": "my-sample-solution",
        "id": "fafafafa-1776-0911-bead-abbadabba123",
        "version": "2.0.0.0",
        "isDomainIsolated": false,
        "includeClientSideAssets": true,
        "developer": {
            "name": "your-company",
            "websiteUrl": "http://your-company.com",
            "mpnId": "",
            "termsOfUseUrl": "http://your-company.com/home/about#terms",
            "privacyUrl": "http://your-company.com/home/about#privacy"
         }
     },
     "paths": {
         "zippedPackage": "solution/my-sample-solution.spapp"
     }
}
```

The solution was found in the thread related to this GitHub issue: [SharePoint repository issue #6144](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6144)